# Android Studio - WebView full size

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying stuff out in Android studio. It's going pretty well, but just one thing I got stuck with. How do I make the WebView activity use full screen size?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYJoP.png

Answer (score 0):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Before the setContentView

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

in Activity oncreate method

Comment: And where do I find setContentView? (Yea. I'm a newb. No need to tell me ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. this worked for me

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

If you are using `WebView` in another Layout such as `LinearLayout` don't give padding to that layout...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to hide `ActionBar` too then goto your manifest file and in your activity tag use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

```
<activity
   android:name=".YourActivityName" 
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```